# how to v-for loop data, but display it according to input of model

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I'm brand new to Vue.js, so forgive my lack of correct terminology...

https://jsfiddle.net/msoutherton/eywraw8t/203188/

The above link is a start (but unfinished) app that hopefully gives you an idea of what I'm going for. I'm trying to build a label-printer that would allow users to customize what data they want to print. Similar to how Microsoft Word can handle mail merges, if you're familiar with that.

In my new Vue app instance, I have some data...

```
el: '#app',
data: {
  labels: [
    {
      FirstName: 'Michael',
      LastName: 'Scott'
    },
    {
      FirstName: 'Pam',
      LastName: 'Beesly'
    },
    ...etc...
  ]
}
```

...and I have a loop...

```
<li v-for="label in labels">
  {{ label.FirstName }} {{ label.LastName }}
</li>
```

This works wonderfully so far. What I would like to do next is allow the user to be able to modify themselves the data that's between those < li > tags.

So I've added...

```
<textarea v-model="label_format"></textarea>
```

...and I've added label_format to my app data so that there is a default value...

```
data: {
  label_format: '{{ FirstName }} {{ LastName }} ',
  labels : [
    ..etc...
```

...but I'm not sure what to do next so that the data entered into my textarea is then used to display the data. I'm assuming I would need some sort of function to search the input for any {{ strings }} that match my data keys, and then somehow map to that data and display it.

Answer (score 0):

Put `FirstName` and `LastName` in variables:

```
data: { attr1: 'FirstName', attr2: 'LastName', labels: [
  {
    FirstName: 'Michael',
    LastName: 'Scott'
  },
  {
    FirstName: 'Pam',
    LastName: 'Beesly'
  }]
}
```

Then use the new variables for "variable" output in the HTML:

```
<li v-for="label in labels">
  {{ label[attr1] }} {{ label[attr2] }}
</li>
```

Then create a way to let the user define `attr1` and `attr2`, for example using

```
<select v-model="attr1"><option v-for="prop in Object.keys(labels[0])">{{ prop }}</option></select>
```

element offering the available properties.

I think this should get you started.

Comment: Thank you for your response, but I'm not sure how a < select > containing my attrs would help me. I'm hoping to use the < textarea > to type out my exact layout I would like. Maybe this update would help illustrate it better: https://jsfiddle.net/msoutherton/eywraw8t/203188/
If I manually reverse the order of the names I enter my textarea, like: {{ LastName }}, {{ FirstName}} then I would like all of the labels below to show in that order as well.

Comment: Then you will obviously need to write a parser for these format strings, and on change of that format re-assign `attr1` and `attr2`.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I'll google those concepts a bit more and see what I can come up with, but this might be a little out of my depth for my very first Vue project. I don't necessarily need this app to be JS-driven, so I might settle on a server-side solution since I know right now how I'd write it that way. When I saw how easily some Vue demos render data to the DOM I thought this project might be a good intro.

Comment: Vue is the perfect choice for this. I don't see why you would refrain to the server side, Javascript can do about anything you need.

Comment: Talent, knowledge, time. :) I agree it's the right choice, but I'll get there eventually. I need to ship code today. Thanks for the direction.